# How to use long/lat OR full address in Google Store Locator module?

Tags: 7, location, google-maps

I wonder if there's a way to use EITHER long/lat OR full address for store content type in the [Google Store Locator](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_store_locator) module.

Has anyone done something along those lines?